# Apache 500 internal server error - DJANGO

Tags: python, html, django, apache, ubuntu

I have a problem with the following error message:

> Error: "500 Internal Server Error"

İ start django project on apache2.

**APACHE2 CONF FİLE:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin biisguzar@gmail.com
ServerName asistan.com
ServerAlias www.asistan.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/asistan


Alias /static/ /var/www/asistan/static/
WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/www/asistan/asistan/wsgi.py"


<Directory /var/www/asistan>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

**DJANGO WSGİ.PY FİLE:**

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append('/var/www')
sys.path.append('/var/www/asistan')

sys.path.append('/var/www/asistan/asistan')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "asistan.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**PAGE SS:**

[image]

Comment: Did you check the apache error logs for exceptions related to this Django application?

Answer (score 2):

In your settings.py make sure you have set the variable ALLOWED_HOSTS to include the name of your domain.  If not you'll get a 500 error whenever the variable DEBUG is set to False.  For example:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mydomain.com']
```

[Here's the documentation for ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)